# Problem with baked lights

Tags: rendering, lighting, unity

I'm working on a 3D gallery experience and I'm having some difficulties regarding directional and point baked lights.

When I build it for web with webgl, only global lights are rendered, but when my prefabs are triggered those rooms comes with the directional/point lights perfectly working, and all planes and lights have the same config... I have spend to much time trying to get them right or understanding why is this happening, any help would be appreciated.

[image: prefab room]
[image: scene]
[image: quality settings]
[image: light settings]
[image: point bdirectional lights settings]
[image: plane settings]